# Access 2016 - Call FORM from .net aplicatión

Tags: .net, ms-access-2016, office-2016

I hope you are doing fine,

The idea is to make the application in access with the forms. For business logic use store procedure.
Then call the forms made in Access 2016 from web app made in .net.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: "Then call the forms made in Access 2016 from web app made in .net." what do you mean by that? Do you mean the user will get the forms via internet? Like in a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Some Assumptions need to be understood.

1. Access can link to Tables & Views for data retrieval and modification.
2. Access can execute SProc's on a RDBMS that is registered, ODBC style
3. Forms are used for data-entry, for the most part, and would need to leverage Table access
4. Forms can execute SProc's on remote RDBMS

With these assumptions out the way.

You will need to programmatically (VBA) code the Insert, Update, and Delete functionality of the Form(s).  Unless you have a one-size-fits-all SProc to do your CRUD.  In which case, you would still have to program the Form to operate the various scenarios to execute the various signatures of the SProc.

### Suggestion

1. Have your Form use a Linked Table/View to acquire a snapshot of the data to be edited
2. Program (VBA) the Insert, Update, and Delete features of the form.